# calculating shape area with methods

Tags: java

Hi I'm new to programming im trying to use submodules to find out the area of a circle.

im supposed to have just circleCalc in main and all the input and outputs seperate in submodules.

could i get some help with this please? and also some explanation with the return types , im not really sure what void does

```
import java.util.*;
public class shapeCalc
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
     double circleCalc, circle;
     circleCalc();

    }

    public static double intInput(String inputStatement)
    {
        double diameter;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(inputStatement);
        diameter = sc.nextInt();
        return diameter;
    }

    public static double calcCircleArea(double diameter)
    {
        double radius, area;
        radius = (double)diameter / 2.0;
        area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        return area;
    }

    public static String extractOutput (double area)
    {
        String output;
        double fraction, mm, m, cm;
        fraction = area - (int)area;
        mm = fraction *100.0;
        m = (int)area / 10000;
        cm = (int)area % 10000;
        System.out.println("area is" + m + cm + mm);
    }

    public static void circleCalc ()
    {
        double diam, area, extractOutput;
        diam = intInput("enter diameter");
        area = calcCircleArea(diam);
        extractOutput(area);
    }
}
```

Comment: `submodules` is a term which I might expect to see in a Git question, but not Java.  I think you mean to say "methods."  `void` is a return type, actually indicating that a method returns nothing.

Comment: I too am confused about what you mean (or your professor means) by submodules. Other than that it seems to me you have solved the problem — congrats. You probably have an error message that `extractOutput()` was supposed to return a `String` and doesn’t. Since this method prints to `System.out` itself, I figure it doesn’t need to return a string, so you may want to change its return type like `public static void extractOutput(double area)`.

Comment: sorry i was meant to say methods i have changed to public static void extractOutput but now im getting an error saying shapeCalc.java:7: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to double
    circle = circleCalc(); @OleV.V.

Comment: I am not getting that error message in my Eclipse. I also cannot see a line `circle = circleCalc();`in your code (only `circleCalc();` and `area = calcCircleArea(diam);`). You may want to edit the question and update the code to what yours looks like now. All I get for now is some warnings about unused local variables (you should get rid of those, but it’s a different story).

Answer (score 0):

method with void return type returns nothing. 
Looking into your question, it seems you want to print/display Area .
So I have made few modifications to your existing code ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Area :" + circleCalc());
    }

public static double intInput(String inputStatement) {
no change;}

public static double calcCircleArea(double diameter) {
no change;}

public static String extractOutput(double area) {
        String output;
        double fraction, mm, m, cm;
        fraction = area - (int) area;
        mm = fraction * 100.0;
        m = (int) area / 10000;
        cm = (int) area % 10000;
        output = String.valueOf(m + cm + mm);
        return output;
    }
 public static String circleCalc() {
        double diam, area;
        diam = intInput("enter diameter");
        area = calcCircleArea(diam);
        return extractOutput(area);
    }
```